# How to map a function over multiple constructor arguments working with Monad class in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads

The problem I'm stumbled at has to do with `>>=` application to a sample type like that:

```
data ThreeArgs a = ThreeArgs a a a deriving (Show,Eq)

instance Functor ThreeArgs where
    fmap f (ThreeArgs a b c) = ThreeArgs (f a) (f b) (f c)

instance Applicative ThreeArgs where
    pure x = ThreeArgs x x x
    (ThreeArgs a b c) <*> (ThreeArgs p s q) = ThreeArgs (a p) (b s) (c q)
```

I'd declare a Monad instance as follows:

```
instance Monad ThreeArgs where
    return x = ThreeArgs x x x
    (ThreeArgs a b c) >>= f = f ... -- a code I need to complete
```

Yes, it looks as if `f` to be applied to all three `ThreeArgs` contructor arguments. If I complete last line

```
(ThreeArgs a b c) >>= f = f a
```

then compiler doesn't have any complaints, whereas result is:

```
*module1> let x = do { x <- ThreeArgs 1 2 3; y <- ThreeArgs 4 6 7; return $ x + y }
*module1> x
ThreeArgs 5 5 5
```

it means that summation results into a context with same argument values, although correct output should be `ThreeArgs 5 8 10`. Once I edit to

```
(ThreeArgs a b c) >>= f = (f a) (f b) (f c)
```

compiler alerts:

```
 Couldn't match expected type `ThreeArgs b
                                -> ThreeArgs b -> ThreeArgs b -> ThreeArgs b'
              with actual type `ThreeArgs b'
```

So, I see a serious mistake guides my comprehension, but it's still rather hard to me to understand monadic class and another such things in Haskell. Presumably, do I want to use recursion here or what else?

Comment: I couldn't say for sure, but my intuition is that no "sensible" Monad instance (one that uses all 3 contained values, and in particular one that gives the result you intend for that example) is possible for this type. Do you have any insight into what the type is supposed to represent? And have you already made `Functor` and `Applicative` instances?

Comment: I've added some code for both instance of Functor and Applicative s well. This problem to be managed so that after putting in `do { x <- ThreeArgs 1 2 3; y <- ThreeArgs 4 6 7; return $ x + y }` the program runs to `ThreeArgs 5 8 10`.

Comment: Thanks, those instances are as I expected, but just wanted to make sure. The reason I think there is no Monad instance here is that your type is now basically a [ZipList](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:ZipList) restricted to having exactly 3 elements. And there is no Monad instance for `ZipList` (although I don't know how to prove there can never be one). Further, I expect restricting to exactly 3 elements will make making an instance more difficult, rather than easier.

Comment: @tex All three values are of type `a`, though. The `Functor` instance is fine. `fmap id (ThreeArgs a b c) == ThreeArgs a b c`, and `fmap (f . g) (ThreeArgs a b c) == ThreeArgs (f (g a)) (f (g b)) (f (g c)) == fmap f (ThreeArgs (g a) (g b) (g c))`.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Actually, the restriction does make it easier, in that it moves it from impossible to possible.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica - thanks, I'm happy to be corrected!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ThreeArgs` is isomorphic to `((->) Ordering)`. Witness:

```
to :: ThreeArgs a -> Ordering -> a
to (ThreeArgs x _ _) LT = x
to (ThreeArgs _ y _) EQ = y
to (ThreeArgs _ _ z) GT = z

from :: (Ordering -> a) -> ThreeArgs a
from f = ThreeArgs (f LT) (f EQ) (f GT)
```

Your `Functor` and `Applicative` instances match how the ones for `((->) r)` work, so we can just make it match how [its `Monad` one](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-828) works too and we're done.

```
instance Monad ThreeArgs where
    ThreeArgs x y z >>= f = ThreeArgs x' y' z' where
        ThreeArgs x' _ _ = f x
        ThreeArgs _ y' _ = f y
        ThreeArgs _ _ z' = f z
```

By the way, the general term for data structures like `ThreeArgs` is "representable functor", if you want to look up more about this.

Comment: It's fine answer as I catch on some essential things about monads due to your explanation. Positively, I've considered any option to skip Monad instance, but it was compulsory to seek a solution which involves that. Things are spotlighted well, thank you.